# Read properties file in java having particular string

Tags: java, properties-file

I am using one `.properties` file. In that I have following config parameters :

```
Appnameweb = app1
Appnamemobile = app2
Appnameweb1 = app3
```

There can be many config param starting with Appname provided by user. 
How to read all properties file parameters in which key will contain particular String like in this case Appname?

Comment: How are you reading the property file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally take a look on javadoc of `java.util.Properties`. To make you life easier I will give you this code snippet that can help you to start:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("myfile.properties"));
for (Enumeration<?> e = props.propertyNames(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    String name = (String)e.nextElement();
    String value = props.getProperty(name);
    // now you have name and value
    if (name.startsWith("Appname")) {
        // this is the app name. Write yor code here
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexR Enumeration<String> e = props.getNames(); gives an error. getNames() gives a `cannot find symbol`

Comment: @Nina, `getNames()` indeed does not exist in class `Properties`. I used existing method `propertyNames()`, and  have no idea where have you found `getNames()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("file.properties"));
Enumeration<String> e = props.getNames();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
    String param = (String) e.nextElement();
    if(param != null && param.contains("Appname")) { 
         values.add(props.getProperty(param));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using java [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), then you can do something on the lines of this.

1. Get the `Set<Object>` of keys using the `Properties#keySet()` method.
2. Start a `for` loop and for each object in the key set, convert the `Object` to `String` either by a cast or using the `toString()` method.
3. With the converted String, check if it contains the common string "Appname" using the `String#contains()` or `String#startsWith()`method depending on your needs.
4. If it does, get the value for that key using the `Properties#getProperty()` method and do whatever you want with the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties"));
        Set<Object> set = prop.keySet();

        for(Object obj : set){
            String str = obj.toString();
            if(str.startsWith("Appname")) {
                //System.out.println("");
            }
        }
```