# JAVA parse properties file with similar numbered keys

Tags: java, properties

I have a properties file as such:

```
BOX1.ThisKey1 = 1
BOX1.ThisKey2 = 9
BOX1.ThisKey3 = 8
BOX1.ThisKey4 = 7
BOX1.ThisKey5 = 6
BOX2.ThisKey1 = 9
```

I currently "manually" parse through the file because I know how many BOX1.ThisKey items I have. This is the code I use to do that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < = 5 i++) {
   String thisString = "BOX1.ThisKey" + i;
   if(properties.containsKey(thisString)) {
      processKeyValue();
   }
}
```

However, the properties file is going to change such that there will be more BOX1.ThisKey items that will be added. I will not have knowledge of how many will be added, and I'd like to know how I can access all of the BOX1.ThisKey values that will be added.

Comment: If the numbers are going to be continuous, just loop until you get a not-found. Or else just loop until some stupidly high number like 100,000. Each lookup is *O(1)* so it won't take long.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510375/read-properties-file-in-java-having-particular-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all keys then filter：

```
Reader reader = new FileReader(new File("filename.txt"));
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(reader);

properties.keySet().stream()
    .filter(o -> o.toString().contains("BOX1.ThisKey"))
    .forEach(o -> {
        String value = properties.getProperty(o.toString());
        processKeyValue(value);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `keySet` and do a comparison with your `BOX1.ThisKey` and process.

```
properties.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
    if (((String) key).startsWith("BOX1.ThisKey")) {
        processKeyValue();
    }
});
```